# Drupal 8 Title tag - head-placeholder

Tags: theming, 8

I am using a custom theme with Stable as a base.

I am trying to figure out how to set the `<title>` tag and I'm having a hard time.

I noticed in `html.html.twig` there is the following:

`<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">`

How does the page title find it's way into the above?

Comment: why does it matter? it's magic :D

Comment: Sure, but at the moment it's a mystery.  I can't figure out how to set the title tag of my site's front page.  How do you use this magic?

Comment: Where and how do you want to set the title? The title is functionality, defined by the route/controller of the request and should automatically be added to the page. Why would you want to change that from your theme?

Comment: @Berdir, Thanks, I will check out routes and controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way but I'm not sure if it's ideal:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['head_title']['title'] = 'title here';
}
```

Logic can be added for each page:

```
$path = $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
if ($path === '...')
```

Then, in `html.html.twig`:

```
<title>{{ head_title.title }}</title>
```

instead of

```
<title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```